# .tostring() preserve leading zeros

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Converting an object .tostring() removes the leading zeros.  The object is not a fixed length, so I can't do object.tostring("0000000") where the number of zeros represents the fixed length.

An example object value is "0357" when I convert that object .tostring it becomes "357".

Is there a method for keeping the leading zeros where the length is not known?

Comment: If the object is a numeric type then its value is `357`, *not* `0357`.

Comment: It's not numeric, it's text, hence converting it using .tostring()

Comment: If it's already text then there's no need to call `ToString` and no need to worry about leading zeroes; just display it (or do whatever it was that you needed to do with it).

Comment: object value is "0357" ==> This should already be a string, It cannot be a number.
Reason:  Guess how many leading zero's are their in 357?

Answer (score 2):

```
object.ToString("D7")
```

Where `7` represents the number of digits to fill.

357 == 0000357

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

Comment: It's not a fixed length as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Should the result be fixed length? If so then this will work fine regardless of the length of the initial string. This will make whatever the initial string is to 7 chars, or whatever you specify. Are you trying to always add a fixed amount of zeros to the front?

Comment: The result is not and should not be a fixed length.

Comment: If the object's value is "0357" the output should be "0357" if the object's value is "00357" the output should be "00357".

Comment: @s15199d - If (value s/b 4 digits) Then object.ToString("D4") ElseIf (value s/b 5 digits) object.ToString("D5") etc. I'm really not certain how the value can be stored without knowing how long it should be.

Comment: If that is it, why not juse prepend the "0" to it, you are not really padding at all. `s = "0" + s;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

```
Dim formatString As String = String.Format("{0:0000}", value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not .tostring()...I was opening the resulting dataset (a *.csv file) in Excel...Excel was truncating the leading zeros.

Comment: If you put an apostrophe, ', before the number-string in the csv file then Excel treats the remainder as text so '00356,'00123,'0123 will preserve the leading zeros and keep them as text.

Answer (score -1):

One way to output to excel/csv file while retaining leading zero is make sure it writes to excel like this: `="0000000000"`

The following example will remind excel to treat `bill_to_num` as a string:

```
Response.Write("=\""+ dr["bill_to_num"].ToString() + "\"" + "\t");
```

Comment: This question does not have anything to do with Excel.