# 12, 11, 10, 9, 8 to 12, 11, 10, 09, 08 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

timer counts down like this 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9  i'm wondering how can make the 9 to 09 when counting down, so it would be like 11, 10, 09, 08, 07 - 00, i've tried goggling, but i'm not accurate with keywords for searching

My Code on timer

```
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
    If hours_label.Text = "" Then
        hours_label.Text = "0"
    End If
    If minutes_label.Text = "" Then
        minutes_label.Text = "0"
    End If
    If seconds_label.Text = "" Then
        seconds_label.Text = "0"
    End If
    If hours_label.Text = "00" Then
        hours_label.Text = "0"
    End If
    If minutes_label.Text = "00" Then
        minutes_label.Text = "0"
    End If
    If seconds_label.Text = "00" Then
        seconds_label.Text = "0"
    End If
    If seconds_label.Text > "0" Then
        seconds_label.Text = seconds_label.Text - 1
    End If
    If minutes_label.Text > "0" Then
        If seconds_label.Text = "0" Then
            minutes_label.Text = minutes_label.Text - 1
            seconds_label.Text = "59"
        End If
    End If
    If hours_label.Text > "0" Then
        If minutes_label.Text = "0" Then
            If seconds_label.Text = "0" Then
                hours_label.Text = hours_label.Text - 1
                minutes_label.Text = "59"
                seconds_label.Text = "59"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If hours_label.Text = "0" Then
        If minutes_label.Text = "0" Then
            If seconds_label.Text = "0" Then
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                msgbox("Times Up")
                Screen_Locker.Show()
                Me.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Thank you for your answers in advance

Comment: on tick, counter--, format counter as left padded with zeros. job done. 2 or 3 lines of code.

Comment: i'm new in programming. do know much yet. Thanks Mitch

Comment: possible duplicate of [.tostring() preserve leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961248/tostring-preserve-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should give you a head-start: use [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function

```
Dim i As Integer = 15
While i >= 0
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0"c))
    i = i - 1
End While
```

How it works: If value is 2 digits e.g. 14, it remains the same but if it's 1 digit, '0' is appended before it to make it 2 digits (string with 2 characters)

```
12 = 12
11 = 11
10 = 10
 9 = 09
...
 0 = 00
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') - i get an error "Expression expected" on the (2,)

Comment: Try `.PadLeft(2, "0"c)`. That was a C# syntax. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Dim s As String
s=Format(Integer,"0#")
```

Just replace Integer with value or variable you want to format. That means that first character will be 0 if there wouldn't be anything there (Integer is less then 10), and second character is digit.

Answer (score 0):

Or use string format from @srka with little bid less code:

```
Dim number As Int32 = 6
number.ToString("0#")
```